# symfony2 many to many entity form

Tags: forms, authentication, symfony, many-to-many

I have two entites `User` `Role`. Both are used in Symfony2 for authentication. The authentication process needs to have method 'getRoles' in class User which returns array.
On the other hand there is form builder which needs roles given as Collection. 
How can i force form builder to use specific getter to get Collection of roles?

```
 class UserType extends AbstractType{
 //...
 ->add('roles', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
                                    'property' => 'name',
                                    'required' => false, 
                                    'multiple' => true,
                                    'expanded' => true,
                                    );

 //...
  }


 class User implements UserInterface {
 //...
    public function getRoles() {
    return $this->roles->toArray();  //This needs authentication mechanism
   }

 public function getRolesCollection() {
    return $this->roles;            //This needs form builder.
}
 //...
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you swap it? logically getRoles should be returning the collection. I don't understand why you're doing the ->toArray in the first place. what's the use case?

Comment: It's because Symfony's authentication process needs array to work properly. Without ->toArray it throws exception `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be an array, object given,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to invert it all :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType{
 //...
 ->add('rolesCollection', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
                                    'property' => 'name',
                                    'required' => false, 
                                    'multiple' => true,
                                    'expanded' => true,
                                    );

 //...
  }


 class User implements UserInterface {
  protected $rolesCollection
 //...
    public function getRoles() {
    return $this->rolesCollection->toArray();  //This needs authentication mechanism
   }

 public function getRolesCollection() {
    return $this->rolesCollection;            //This needs form builder.
}
 //...
 }
```